# Autocomplete from generic Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Hi everyone!

```js
type AnyParamConstructor<T> = new (...args: unknown[]) => T;

class EntityA {}
class EntityB {}
class ModelA {}
class ModelB {}

class Modeler {
  constructor(private entities: AnyParamConstructor<unknown>[]) {}

  public getModel<T extends typeof this.entities>(entity: T) {
    // Here I need entity to be EntityA or EntityB. Not a string
    // Alternativ I need a solution like: get Entity from string
    if (entity === EntityA) {
      return ModelA;
    } else if (entity === EntityB) {
      return ModelB;
    }
  }
}

const modeler = new Modeler([EntityA, EntityB]);
const modelA = modeler.getModel(EntityA);
const modelAFromString = modeler.getModel('EntityA');
const modelB = modeler.getModel(EntityB);
const modelBFromString = modeler.getModel('EntityB');
```

I have a constructor that takes an array of entities. Depending from this array I would like to have the parameter from `getModel` to autocomplete `EntityA` and `EntityB`. I would prefer the method to autocomplete strings but then I need a solution from getting an Entity from a string. So the second variant would be ok, but I don't know if it is possible to autocomplete types.

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiACgQwE7ILYGED2cDOwqArgMbA6oA8AKgHxQC8UcEA7lABQB0vaA5vgBcUYnADWcHGzgBtALoBKJgxoBuAFAbSAG2T58UAKJxgAS1AwoAbwC+2vQeOmLIAEI37u-YYCyOABMIHSs7Bx8ofyCdDzDwpyjgiFQbDSgoUjxCEnJKTjBUMwA3ZGBoCBdzCGFYBBR0bCyiMgpqMUlpODoFZTj0sGIAIx0zUih+CGBEnVooCAAPMrgAw1BIHAAzKGAACzN8bgrzKvw6TiPXERpetPSoAHp7qAAJZOgASRYICAC5ypBtjgoINoCZjiArJRnOC3NwoAA5HDAKDIKDZMxwfi3dKPWA6MqoOClYpQT6sH4otE4HTEcx4KAjcQQEQTZFg1xQDaoHAYNFEDFYu5QMxbc7-JiMZjsyw3IXpVCTYiEyKBYIwTRC2xzHT4aAirgXUASqX-NyyuUK4BKuAq6JuDV3ezpez2bRNKAYVU6ZJML4cabJTiyaUQgA00NcbiUmkyBGRnuiVmYCaSqG4rOmnBDMEUMfdKZCADFuRgAMr8zG+gvJdOTTMAcmz9dzbrjHq9HmTXprGa9WdNLdjhHbduLPPLhUrXeiPbrfcbpubmiAA).

Comment: Uh, how are you supposed to know which model to return? I don't think *hardcoding* a map of entities to models is feasible...

Comment: You can't get the names of classes. The next best thing would be to provide an object literal with property initializer shorthand: https://tsplay.dev/WG8GXw It's similar to providing an array syntactically anyways.

Comment: Unfortunately not. There is a third party function that takes entities. And the `Modeler` should be closed so other developers can use it.

Comment: Yeah, so I'm not sure how we're supposed to correctly type the return type of the method? I demonstrated how you could type the parameters above, though.

Comment: The approach you suggest might be a solution. Let me think about it.

Comment: Ok, I thing `your suggestion` https://tsplay.dev/Wvkz3w is a solution I like. I would go with the non string variant. But why does it work? Why is there an override necessary? And what does it do?

Comment: *Overloads* are in place so we don't have to deal with TypeScript complaining about our implementation (which will at some point in the future exist), and also so we can define the return types for using a string or entity to get the model *separately*. But again, I have no idea how we're going to get the correct model...

Comment: I think thats fine. The third party function takes any constructor. So this should work. I could change the question to reflect that.

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/Wyo2ZN This works for me